# How can I install Extra CMake Modules on Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty)

Tags: 14.04, software-installation

I'm trying to build something from source using CMake that is intended for the current (16.04 - Xenial) build.  It seems to depend on ECM which seems to be Extra CMake Modules (aka extra-cmake-modules on Xenial).  It doesn't seem to be available for 14.04.

Any ideas how to get it, or instructions as to where I can download the source and build a package for Trusty, that I could install?

Comment: GAD3R has a great answer for building ECM from source, anyone care to hazard how to build it to a trusty compatible .deb package from source?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit (Brought to top)**

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/extra-cmake-modules
cd extra-cmake-modules
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. # or run : cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr .. &&
make
sudo make install
```

You can install the latest `qt` version as follows:

```
wget http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/5.7/5.7.0/qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run
chmod +x qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run
./qt-opensource-linux-x64-5.7.0.run
```

**Original answer**

The `extra-cmake-modules` is available on [Ubuntu 16.04 , 16.10 and 17.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=extra-cmake-modules) version.

> No summary available for extra-cmake-modules in [ubuntu utopic](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+package/extra-cmake-modules).

You can install it on Ubuntu 14.04 but it is not recommended , it can break your System.

You can edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` then add the following line:

```
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe
```

Then update your system **some dependencies will be upgraded**

to install it run:

```
sudo apt install extra-cmake-modules
```

Comment: As you say, simply pointing my sources at xenial, is a recipe for disaster.  No, I want a safe way to install the library on trusty, either by package or source.

Comment: Ok i will edit my answer

Comment: That's good, I'll try that now.  Any idea how to make a package, so I can let dpkg manage it, rather than relying on make install?  I think if I'm relying on make install then I'd rather it builds in /usr/local than clutter /usr

Comment: Also FYI my company firewall doesn't allow SSH connections to the big bad world, so I had to use git clone https://anongit...

Comment: And, kpmcore2.2 requires qt5.3 and so I'm back to square one.  Thanks loads anyway, this definitely answered my question.  Now how to get qt5.3 on trusty :-)

Comment: (I'd still like to know how to build this as a package though, if you care to extend your answer)

Comment: @sibaz run `sudo apt-get install qt5-default`

Comment: Yep, tried that, its 5.2.1 not 5.3

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the previous answer from GAD3R that does not work for me cloning the `extra-cmake-modules` repository, here is an alternative solution:

```
git clone https://github.com/KDE/extra-cmake-modules.git
```